# Output of the table in div class

Tags: php, class, html, output

```
$resultSet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7");
$product_count = mysql_num_rows($resultSet);
   if($product_count >0){

    while( mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)){
        $id= $row["id"];
        $cat= $row["categories"];
        $title= $row["title"];
        $image= $row["image"];
        $txt= $row["txt"];
        $res= $row["resource"];

        }
   }
     else  
        { echo'site is under maintaince ';}

       echo " <div class=\"row-fluid\">

     <div class=\"span6 post no-margin-left\">
      <figure>
       <img src=\"$image\" alt=\"Thumbnail 1\" />
       <div class=\"cat-name\">
        <span class=\"base\">'$cat'</span>
        <span class=\"arrow\"></span>
       </div>
      </figure>
      <div class=\"text\">
       <h2><a href=\"single_post.html\" title=\"$title\">'$title'</a></h2>
       <p>$txt</p>
       <div class=\"meta\">By <a href=\"$res\">' $res'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;'$date'&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"single_post.html\">15 comments</a></div>
      </div>
     </div>

       </div>";
   ?>
```

The code is not showing the output results of the table. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I want to show the output in the div class. My paging is working correctly, but it is not showing the output correctly. Can you guide me? I will really be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

```
while( mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)){
        $id= $row["id"];
        $cat= $row["categories"];
        $title= $row["title"];
        $image= $row["image"];
        $txt= $row["txt"];
        $res= $row["resource"];

        }
   }
```

Where is $row in the lopp? However, to populate all the results, you need the printing inside the loop, otherwise you won't get them iterated

Comment: i tried to put the value in while look but it showing only text not faching result from mysql table

Comment: yes, your $row variable is not assigned to the fetched array. `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)) {` in your case